# Slow MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have tried everything to make this query faster that I know of. Same engine for every table, indexes on all the fields which are used for joins, order by or where clauses.

The problem seems to be tables `aam` and `ag` are not using an index despite there being indexes available.

Query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT `a`.`id`, `a`.`full_name`, `a`.`rating`, `a`.`licence`, `a`.`licence_issued`, `ag`.`name` as agency_name
FROM (`property_suburb_map` psm)
JOIN `campaign_property_map` cpm ON `psm`.`property_id` = `cpm`.`property_id`
JOIN `campaign` c ON `cpm`.`campaign_id` = `c`.`id`
JOIN `campaign_agent_map` cam ON `cpm`.`campaign_id` = `cam`.`campaign_id`
JOIN `agent` a ON `cam`.`agent_id` = `a`.`id`
JOIN `agency_agent_map` aam ON `aam`.`agent_id` = `a`.`id`
JOIN `agency` ag ON `aam`.`agency_id` = `ag`.`id`
WHERE `c`.`closing_date` >= '2009-10-12'
AND `psm`.`suburb_id` = '5911'
AND `a`.`status` = 'Active'
ORDER BY `a`.`rating` DESC, `a`.`full_name`
LIMIT 12
```

Explain (sorry, formatting got messed up):  Use this image instead http://imgur.com/UzSpC.jpg

```
id  select_type     table           type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra

1   SIMPLE          a               ref     PRIMARY,status  status  1   const   790     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE          aam             ref     agency_id_2,
                                            agent_id,
                                            agency_id       agent_id      4     hindsight.a.id  1    
1   SIMPLE          ag              eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   hindsight.aam.agency_id     1    
1   SIMPLE          cam             ref     agent_id,
                                            campaign_id     agent_id    4   hindsight.a.id  9   Distinct
1   SIMPLE          c               eq_ref  PRIMARY,closing_date    PRIMARY     4   hindsight.cam.campaign_id   1   Using where; Distinct
1   SIMPLE          cpm             ref     campaign_id     campaign_id     4   hindsight.c.id  1   Using where; Using index; Distinct
1   SIMPLE          psm             ref     property_id,suburb_id   property_id     4   hindsight.cpm.property_id   1   Using where; Distinct
```

Here is the relevant structure of the database http://pastebin.com/Rbyrj6x3

**Edit** I have done a profile on the query: `Copying to tmp table` is really slow.

```
mysql> show profile for query 6;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000000 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000000 |
| System lock          | 0.000000 |
| Table lock           | 0.000000 |
| init                 | 0.000000 |
| optimizing           | 0.000000 |
| statistics           | 0.000000 |
| preparing            | 0.000000 |
| Creating tmp table   | 0.000000 |
| executing            | 0.000000 |
| Copying to tmp table | 0.112000 |  <- WTF!
| Sorting result       | 0.004000 |
| Sending data         | 0.000000 |
| end                  | 0.000000 |
| removing tmp table   | 0.000000 |
| end                  | 0.000000 |
| query end            | 0.000000 |
| freeing items        | 0.000000 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000000 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000000 |
+----------------------+----------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The explain shows that the indexes on aam and ag ARE being used.  I don't understand why you think that they are not being used.

Comment: I'm not an expert at reading explains, but would have assumed that `Using index` would show up on the right (Extra). Thanks for correcting me. If all the indexes are being used I'm not sure where the bottle neck is. Removing the where and order clauses has no significant effect on performance it still takes over 1 second.

Comment: The 'key' column in the explain output shows which key was chosen.  If that contains a NULL, then no index is used.  "using index" indicates that some sort of index-scan (rather than index seek) is being used.

Comment: **Edit** Found this bug http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html I will need to rewrite this somehow since MySQL is a toy database.

Comment: @Keyo - your link in the comments is to an article describing the MySQL profiler, not to a bug.  What bug are you referring to ?

Comment: Sorry, this is the one http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,39066,39066#msg-39066

Answer (score 1):

Do you have foreign keys on all fields of all tables?
Please describe your tables

Comment: Nope, would this help? See the pastebin link above for a dump of the tables. Maybe this is what InnoDB needs to know which index to use?

Comment: Can you rename fields in tables? Just for natural joins and simplifying query. Then add foreign keys for all linked field

Answer (score 1):

Try turning the index on agent.status into a covering index by adding agent_id as a second component:

```
create index idx2 on agent( status, id)
```

This might enable the query to eliminate more of the agent rows before having to retrieve records from the data table.

Comment: This improved performance a little, maybe 10%, but not a huge amount. Maybe my database server is just slow. On my localhost development server it runs at around 0.12 seconds. On the production server it's about 1.8 seconds. Is this a normal speed for this type of query?

Comment: It is strange that your production server is slower:  is that because there is more data on it ?

Comment: For the explain output, 0.12 seconds seems OK.  The main problem is that it is pulling a lot of rows out of the agent table before resolving anything else - hence the slow temporary table.  It is strange that your production server is slower:  is that because there is more data on it ?   Can you add the output from "show variables" ?

Comment: I'm not so much concerned that it's slower, the server has many sites on it. My workstation is mostly idle.

Comment: Another small improvement could be made by altering the indexes on campaign_agent_map so you have key(agent_id, campaign_id):  this will allow the joins agent -> cam -> campaign to resolve using the index without pulling rows from the cam table.

Comment: Also, the composite key on aam is the wrong way round to help this query:  it would be better as key( agent_id, agency_id) - again to avoid hitting disk.

Comment: Also, if the composite keys on cam and cpm can be made into unique indexes, the join type becomes eq_ref instead of ref, which is more efficient.